# Problem with Arraylist and Hashmap when populating Listview

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, listview

I am trying to get the Data from my JSON file to HashMap and then to my Arraylist and it should be displayed in the Listview. But it doesnt show anything. Could you pls help me?

public class SendPostRequest extends AsyncTask {

```
    String data ="";
    protected void onPreExecute(){}

    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

       try{


                JSONArray json = new JSONArray(data);
                ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>  arrayList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                try {
                for(int i=0;i<json.length();i++){
                    JSONObject e =json.getJSONObject(i);

                    map.put("id", String.valueOf(i));
                    map.put("Name", "Vorname: " + e.getString("meta_value"));
                    map.put("orderid", "id: " + e.getString("post_id"));
                    arrayList.add(map);
                    //return map.toString();
                }

                    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(activity2.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrayList);

                }catch (JSONException e){
                    Log.e(this.getClass().getName(), "Some JSON error occurred" + e.getMessage());

                }
                return data;


            }
            else {
                return new String("false : "+responseCode);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow. I would highly suggest that you edit your question following the guidelines of [this StackOverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). As StackOverflow is not meant to be used as a forum to help you debug your code. You may also want to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get more familiar with SO and what is expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To populate your list view you need to add this piece of code after creating your array adapter

```
ListView myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.idOfYourListView)

runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
     myListView.setAdapter( arrayAdapter );
    }
});
```

Comment: it comes the error message: "Exception: Only the original thread that created a view hirarchy con touch this views"

Answer (score 0):

You should replace ListView by RecyclerView from now